# How to create a Toast Notification in WP8 for a daily notification

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have been developing in Windows Phone 8 for a couple of months. Currently, I am developing an app that consume some XML to show data. I know how the Toast notification works in WP8, however my doubt is about the following:

In the App I am working on, I would like to implement a kind of **Toast Notification** when a new data is available (from the source where the XML is extracted). So, is it possible? If so, how to implement it in **WP8**?

I don't know if you are familiar with the App of dictionary.com. In that App, there is an option to enable the notification for the word of the day. So, every day I recieve a different word in english. When I click in the notification I can see it's meaning.

Any clue, link, post, code or suggestion would be very appreciate

Thanks in advance

Regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can be many ways. My idea will be to use Azure Mobile Services. To explain, let me take same fictitious Dictionary.com example. The WP app will be bound to Azure Mobile Service and it will show all the words fetched from that service. Whenever, I add a new word to this service, using Push Notifications, it will send notification to all my users who've installed Dictionary.com app, stating new word is added.
You can find more information here: [click here](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/tutorials/get-started-with-push-wp8/)